# How to deploy email content in marketing cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

I need to deploy a bunch of emails from one BU to a second one.
I am using the deployment manager but there is no change to deploy email contents.
Is there a way to do that quickly?

Thank you

Comment: Can't you just use shared content, to make these emails available in multiple BUs?

Comment: for this, the BUs must have the same parent BU, right?

Comment: Not necessary, they can be on different levels of a Business Unit hierarchy, as long as they are all part of the same instance.

Comment: they can also be on different accounts

Comment: If the BUs you deploy to are on separate accounts (root BUs with different EIDs) you indeed can't use shared content, but are left with deployment manager.

Comment: if I am not mistaken I can only deploy DE/automation/jb/attrgroup with the deployment manager

Comment: Yes - you are correct. When I write "you are left with deployment manager" I mean with the limitation it has, so no easy way of deploying content.

Comment: You could utilize the API to grab the email content from BU 1 and then use a second API call to push that pulled content to the other BU - but that would require custom development to set up the tool to achieve this.